# HTML to PDF/PostScript using linux command line, How can I do that?

Tags: html, perl, bash, pdf-generation

I'm working on a piece of Shell Script tool that should generate PDF out of HTML. I want to convert the HTML to pdf or postscript without needing to install packages as that needs a lot 
of paper work. Is there an easy way to achieve that ? Any perl code that I can download and use without installing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert from PDF to HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751369/how-to-convert-from-pdf-to-html)

Comment: ```htmldoc --webpage -f file.pdf http://www.example.com/file.html```

Answer (score 4):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) converts any page to PDF rendering via WebKit (qtwebkit). CSS & JavaScript included:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://stackoverflow.com/ stackoverflow.pdf
```

However, on "headless" setups (server, not desktop), I advise to use a minimal X server with the standalone executables provided on the official page:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
Xvfb $DISPLAY &
wkhtmltopdf --use-xserver http://stackoverflow.com/ stackoverflow.pdf
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You could install html2ps and ps2pdf (both are userland perl scripts) and pipe the output of html2ps into ps2pdf

Answer (score 2):

Try [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/), a command-line program which does exactly that, and has good support for modern CSS. It's written in Python, but that shouldn't matter for calling from a shell script.